# Notepad ++ / Extract text betwen ^ ^ and add it, as new line

Tags: notepad++, string-manipulation

I have a text file that I need to extract specific data elements from it ( the person fullname to add it as new line):

ID:363712^CLARK/DEJA G^:e30276c2f826febd3784958:KZxhnbUUouxvMrTEYfGnDZ7YcGjPh

ID:363713^LUTZ/ANTON A^:84cF6F48eAc2b5E223Bf1703:ZD4LLGMqNyNYYtjLycdEds23A2

ID:363714^OATO/GINA D^:GnDZ7YcGjPh6Ru7cEjfQGZgD:GMqNyNYYtjLycdEdcxRijNc7G

---

I want to extract:

DEJA G CLARK
ID:363712^CLARK/DEJA G^:e30276c2f826febd3784958:KZxhnbUUouxvMrTEYfGnDZ7YcGjPh

ANTON A LUTZ
ID:363713^LUTZ/ANTON A^:84cF6F48eAc2b5E223Bf1703:ZD4LLGMqNyNYYtjLycdEds23A2

GINA OATO
ID:363714^OATO/GINA^:GnDZ7YcGjPh6Ru7cEjfQGZgD:GMqNyNYYtjLycdEdcxRijNc7G

Regards

Comment: You should google "RegexBuddy."

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press Ctrl+H
2. Find What:`(.+\^)(.+)(\/)(.+)(\^.+)`
3. Replace with: `$4 $2\n$1$2$3$4$5`
4. Search Mode: REgular Expression
5. Press Replace All

**Before**

[image: IMG:]

**After**

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?\^(.+?)/(.+?)\^.+$`
- Replace with: `$2 $1\n$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \^          # carret, have to be escaped as it's a special character for regex
    (.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    /           # a slash
    (.+?)       # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \^          # carret, have to be escaped as it's a special character for regex
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2 (firstname initial) followed by a space
$1          # content of group 1 (lastname)
\n          # linefeed, you may use \r\n for Windows EOL
$0          # the whole match (i.e. the whole line)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]